# Fluentd-ui: Can I receive / catch data from fiware orion contextbroker which are pushed to mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, docker, fiware-orion, fluentd

I am struggling since weeks with this problem and I hope you can help me with that.

On my Ubuntu Server (16.04) I have installed Docker.
There are three docker containers installed:

- **contextBroker** (from docker image fiware/orion), listens on port: 0.0.0.0:1026->1026/tcp
- **mongoDB** (from docker image mongo), listens on port: 27017/tcp
- **fluentd-ui** (from docker image dvladnik/fluentd-ui), listens on ports: 0.0.0.0:9292->9292/tcp, 0.0.0.0:24224->24224/tcp

Right now, contextBroker is pushing some json format data to mongoDB, which is good.

I started with fluentd-ui, so I am really new on that.

**What do I want?**

I am trying to get these data which are pushed from contextBroker to mongoDB with fluentd-ui. Fluentd-ui should get these data from contextBroker, so that I can procedure further with these data. I am trying to push these data to another db since I have to do other things with that (probably again a mongoDB, but another one) **or / also** pushing these data to elasticsearch / Kibana (I have to do some analysis).

The idea is, that contextBroker is still pushing data to the original mongoDB, but also that fluentd can somehow receive these data from contextBroker.

Is this even possible?
For me it would also be ok, when fluentd is used as a "men in the middle", but it should still push data to mongoDB **and** somewhere else (elasticsearch, etc.).

**How did I run the containers?**

*MongoDB:*

```
sudo docker run --log-driver=fluentd --log-opt tag=docker.mymongodb --name mymongodb -d mongo
```

*ContextBroker:*

```
sudo docker run -d --name cbdocker --link mymongodb:mymongodb --log-driver=fluentd --log-opt tag=docker.mycontextbroker -p 1026:1026 fiware/orion -dbhost mymongodb -logLevel DEBUG
```

**What did I try?**

I tried this:

```
<source>
  type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<match docker.*>
  type stdout
</match>
```

This above only prints the log of mongodb and the contextbroker itself. but not the pushed data (I also added mongodb, just to check if it also could work like this)

I think this makes sense, but I have to subscribe to the contextbroker but how should I do that? Is fluentd possible to do that? Do you think I have to do something like a Java application, which subscribes from contextBroker and fluentd listens on this application or is there a better solution?

---

I honestly would be happy if I only could receive these data, so that I can first print them in a simple logfile (The rest I can check later).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't know fluentd-ui so maybe I'm saying some nonsense :) but... why are you trying to consume context data directly from Orion MongoDB? I mean, Orion database is only for Orion internal usage (persitance, etc.). You should consume Orion context data using the NGSIv2 API it offers (either synchronously or using the subscriptions/notifications mechanism). Note that database model could change between Orion versions (so ruining your integration) while the API is always backward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to receive the data in an application and then login or do something more complex you can use the Orion [subscriptions](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/#subscriptions) mechanism.

Using the subscriptions mechanism of Orion you can be notified when a specific context changes and then receive for example all the context information.

**For example:**

```
curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type:  application/json' \
  -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Room1",
        "type": "Room"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "pressure"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

In the previous example, you are telling the Orion Context Broker to notify you every time there is a change in the "pressure" attribute of the "Romo1" context of type "Room" and then only sends to you "temperature" information.

In case you want to send you all the information you can leave the field "attrs" in "notification" field, empty and then Orion sends to you the whole context information.

Finally in the field notification.url you have to indicate URL to the application that you want to be notified. Keep in mind that if Orion is working inside a Docker Container, this should be able to see your application. For example you should run your app inside the same docker network as Orion.

I recommend you read the [documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/#subscriptions) of Orion regarding subscriptions in order to get a deep dive. It is very good and clear.

Sadly I don't have experience with fluentd-ui so I don't know if you can connect directly with Orion using this mechanism.

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: I don't recommend the usage of "throttling". In addition, consider removing "expires" if you don't actually need subscription expiration. Appart from that, the @EmilianoViotti answer looks perfect! :)